# Is it possible to be informed by email of new questions having a specific keyword?

Tags: support, notifications

I want to be informed by email if any user creates a question that has a specific keyword in the title or content. Is that possible?

Comment: It'd be fun to see my inbox after a few minutes of having subscribed to `javascript`

Comment: :) sure it should have some limits

Comment: You can use the RSS feeds, then use a [RSS to mail service](https://blogtrottr.com/).

Comment: Or simple use the builtin rss reader, every common mail client has @MartijnPieters

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: The Apple Mail client doesn't. Personally, I use inoreader.com for my RSS needs.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt: about [50% of mail clients support RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#Protocol_support).

Comment: Wow, interessting stats @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters We receive new questions for a particular tag once a day. I think what OP is asking for is a new notification in the inbox every time a new question is asked.....

Comment: @JeruLuke: RSS is updated just as often as your RSS reader checks.

Answer (score 25):

You can get email notifications on tags through https://stackexchange.com/filters.

Any filter you set up there not only has a corresponding RSS feed (scroll to bottom of page after making filter), but also gives you the ability to subscribe via email to new questions in that filter:

[image]

Also, adding to [Christian Gollhardt's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345994/616460) if you go the RSS route:

- Here is a list of available RSS feeds: [What other hidden or inobvious RSS feeds are available on Stack Exchange and its sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its)
- There is also [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/#Usage) which can turn any [API query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) into an RSS feed. You could, for example, get a feed on question title text using [`/search`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) (there is no way to search question bodies, as the API docs imply that's intentionally limited).

Also, fwiw, for RSS there's tons of feed reading browser extensions, too, if you want notifications but not emails.

Comment: exactly I receive email notifications for tags I have enlisted once a day. I do not receive emails for every question asked but a receive a notification once a day for all the **new** questions asked that day....

Comment: @JeruLuke: and what frequency did you select for the emails? The screenshot shows you can be emailed every 15 minutes..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really??! I never knew that! I'll check out my my RSS feed again. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

If you go to a tag page, for example [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), you see an RSS Feed option at the end of the page:

[image: RSS]

You can subscribe to it by some mail clients (e.g. Outlook, Thunderbird).

As [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345970/is-it-possible-to-be-informed-by-email-of-new-questions-having-a-specific-keywor#comment459521_345970) pointed out, you could also use an [RSS to mail service](https://blogtrottr.com/), if your Mail Client does not support it.

I don't think, we need a buildin mail option. [RSS is the better protocol](https://blog.spinweb.net/rss-feed-vs-email-subscription-whats-the-difference) for a task like this.

Comment: Adding to this answer, [here is a list of available RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151519/what-other-hidden-or-inobvious-rss-feeds-are-available-on-stack-exchange-and-its), and also [Stack2RSS](http://stack2rss.quickmediasolutions.com/#Usage) exists and can be used to turn any API query into an RSS feed, so e.g. you can get a feed on question titles with [`/search?`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search). There is no way to search question bodies, as the API docs imply that's intentionally limited.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [google alert](https://www.bloggingbasics101.com/how-to-set-up-a-google-alert-and-why-its-a-good-idea/) based in the same criteria used for google searching.

Like when you search in google you can filter the results by site

```
something site:www.mysite.com
```

or containing a word in specific:

```
"this have to exist" rest of the content
```